# Need help configuring NTFS Permissions on a dummy file server

Tags: active-directory, file-sharing, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

I'm playing around with Server 2016 in a VM and created a very basic file share system on the server (which is also the AD, DHCP and DNS server which i know is not the best practice but it'll do for pure testing purposes)

My question is that the file share i've created is meant to emulate end user home drives, i'm struggling on how to get each user to have write access to only their drive folder. I don't want to add the permissions in manually for each user

I've already set the share permissions to have "Everyone" with full control, but not sure how to configure NTFS permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient way to set up user home drives is to use the built-in Active Directory feature for it. On the Profile tab of the Properties window on an AD user object, there is a "Home folder" section. Select "Connect" and enter a path under the share you already created (e.g. `\\server\homes\jsmith`). If the path doesn't yet exist, it will be created for you with NTFS security configured such that the person you're modifying has Full Control. Note that the newly created folder and its security settings remain even if you change the user's home back to nothing.

If you don't want to use the built-in feature, things get less convenient. There is one way to offload some of the work, though. You can set the NTFS ACL on your shared folder such that when a user creates a folder, they alone are granted full access to it and its descendants. In the Advanced Security Settings window (click Advanced on the Security tab of the folder properties), first disable inheritance and do not copy the inherited entries. Then add these permissions:

- Allow SYSTEM full control over "this folder, subfolders, and files"
- Likewise for Administrators
- Allow Users "read & execute," "list folder contents," and "read" on "this folder, subfolders, and files"
- Allow CREATOR OWNER full control over "subfolders and files only"
- Allow Users "create folders / append data" on "this folder only" (you'll need to click "show advanced permissions" to see that)

If you don't want users to be able to read each other's stuff, you can use "this folder only" in the third entry instead. The last two points are where the magic happens. CREATOR OWNER is a placeholder that gets transformed upon file creation into the creator user. It does stick around, however, when subfolders are created. Allowing all users to create folders under the root gives them exactly enough power to take advantage of the CREATOR OWNER principal to produce their own space.